Scaling x_axis in horizontal bar chart
I'm trying to do a race bar chart with view_follow() but I'm struggling on two issues. Here is a sample of my dataset:
df2<-structure(list(Season = c("2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024"), FULLDATE = structure(c(19564, 19564, 
19564, 19564, 19564, 19564, 19564, 19564, 19573, 19573, 19573, 
19573, 19573, 19573, 19573, 19573, 19574, 19574, 19574, 19574, 
19574, 19574, 19574, 19574, 19575, 19575, 19575, 19575, 19575, 
19575, 19575, 19575, 19580, 19580, 19580, 19580, 19580, 19580, 
19580, 19580, 19581, 19581, 19581, 19581, 19581, 19581, 19581, 
19581, 19582, 19582), class = "Date"), League = c("Super League", 
"Jupiler Pro League", "Liga", "LigaNOS", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", 
"Bundesliga", "Serie A", "Super League", "Jupiler Pro League", 
"Liga", "LigaNOS", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", "Bundesliga", 
"Serie A", "Super League", "Jupiler Pro League", "Liga", "LigaNOS", 
"Ligue 1", "Premier League", "Bundesliga", "Serie A", "Super League", 
"Jupiler Pro League", "Liga", "LigaNOS", "Ligue 1", "Premier League", 
"Bundesliga", "Serie A", "Super League", "Liga", "LigaNOS", "Premier League", 
"Ligue 1", "Jupiler Pro League", "Bundesliga", "Serie A", "Super League", 
"Premier League", "LigaNOS", "Liga", "Ligue 1", "Jupiler Pro League", 
"Bundesliga", "Serie A", "Super League", "Ligue 1"), goals = c(3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 25, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 34, 
21, 16, 11, 5, 1, 0, 0, 46, 32), rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L), image_file = c("~/lglogos/Super League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Jupiler Pro League.png", "~/lglogos/Liga.png", "~/lglogos/LigaNOS.png", 
"~/lglogos/Ligue 1.png", "~/lglogos/Premier League.png", "~/lglogos/Bundesliga.png", 
"~/lglogos/Serie A.png", "~/lglogos/Super League.png", "~/lglogos/Jupiler Pro League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Liga.png", "~/lglogos/LigaNOS.png", "~/lglogos/Ligue 1.png", 
"~/lglogos/Premier League.png", "~/lglogos/Bundesliga.png", "~/lglogos/Serie A.png", 
"~/lglogos/Super League.png", "~/lglogos/Jupiler Pro League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Liga.png", "~/lglogos/LigaNOS.png", "~/lglogos/Ligue 1.png", 
"~/lglogos/Premier League.png", "~/lglogos/Bundesliga.png", "~/lglogos/Serie A.png", 
"~/lglogos/Super League.png", "~/lglogos/Jupiler Pro League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Liga.png", "~/lglogos/LigaNOS.png", "~/lglogos/Ligue 1.png", 
"~/lglogos/Premier League.png", "~/lglogos/Bundesliga.png", "~/lglogos/Serie A.png", 
"~/lglogos/Super League.png", "~/lglogos/Liga.png", "~/lglogos/LigaNOS.png", 
"~/lglogos/Premier League.png", "~/lglogos/Ligue 1.png", "~/lglogos/Jupiler Pro League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Bundesliga.png", "~/lglogos/Serie A.png", "~/lglogos/Super League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Premier League.png", "~/lglogos/LigaNOS.png", "~/lglogos/Liga.png", 
"~/lglogos/Ligue 1.png", "~/lglogos/Jupiler Pro League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Bundesliga.png", "~/lglogos/Serie A.png", "~/lglogos/Super League.png", 
"~/lglogos/Ligue 1.png")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

In this particular dataframe, I have 8 leagues, that are shown in the x axis (after coord flip). The problem is they don't fit the plot margin (all blank space below last bar) . I've been trying several workarounds but couldn't make it work.
Besides, I have geom_image() as labels but I'm not able to show them on the left on the axis rather than on the axis.
Here is my code:
colpal<-c('Ligue 1'="#E5174F",'Premier League' ="#99CBE7", 'Liga' = "#122623", 'Bundesliga' = "#00bbf9ff", 'Serie A' ="#3469A6",
          "LigaNOS" = "#5EB1BF","Jupiler Pro League" ="#F6AE2D","Super League" = "#B3001B")
colpal.order<-c('Ligue 1','Premier League', 'Liga', 'Bundesliga', 'Serie A',"LigaNOS","Jupiler Pro League",
                "Super League")

gfb<-ggplot(df2, aes(rank,group=League,fill=factor(League,levels = colpal.order),
                     color = as.factor(League)))+
  geom_tile(aes(y=goals/2,x=rank,height=goals,width = 0.9),alpha = 0.8, color = NA) +
  geom_image(aes(x=rank,image = image_file), y=0,  
             size = 0.05, 
             inherit.aes = FALSE, hjust = 1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colpal)+
  scale_color_manual(values = colpal) +
  coord_flip(clip="off",expand=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_reverse()+
  geom_text(aes(y=goals,label = sprintf("%1.0f", goals)),color="white",fontface = "bold", size = 14,family="Archivo Black",vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)+#
  geom_text(aes(x=+15.5,y=0, label=months(FULLDATE)),size= 5, color="grey")+
  guides(color = guide_none())+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme( panel.grid = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major.x = element_line( linewidth = .5, color="#122623"),
         panel.background = element_rect(colour = NA,fill="transparent"),
         legend.position = "none", 
         axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
         axis.title.y = element_blank(),
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
         axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
         plot.margin = margin(8, 6, 8, 6, "cm"), 
         plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff", color = NA), 
         plot.title = element_text(size = 28, hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold', color = "#21FA90", vjust = 5,family="Archivo Black"), 
         plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 17.5, hjust = 0.5, face = "italic", color = "grey", vjust = 5,family="Archivo Black"),
         plot.caption = element_text(size = 12.5, color = "grey", vjust = 0,family="Archivo Black"),
  ) 
  
  anim <- gfb +
    transition_states(FULLDATE, transition_length = 4, state_length = 2) + 
    view_follow(
      fixed_y = c(0, NA),
      fixed_x = TRUE,
    )+
    
    ease_aes('quadratic-in-out') +
    enter_grow()+
    exit_shrink()+
    labs( title = "Goal scored this season", 
          subtitle = '{closest_state}', 
          caption = 'Source: Hedgeflare calculation') 
anim
  animate(anim, fps = 30, duration =05, width = 1080, height = 1920, renderer = gifski_renderer("gganim15.gif"))

Thank you for your help.

The issue is the annotation you added using geom_text(x = +15.5, ...) which extend the range of the y scale from 8 to 15.5, thereby leaving a huge white space below the last bar. Second, concerning the issues with your league logos one option would be to use ggtext::geom_richtext instead of geom_image which allows to align the images on the right using hjust = 1:
Note: I only use one logo for all leagues.
df2$image_file <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f7/Premier_League_Logo.svg.png"

library(ggplot2)
library(ggimage)
library(gganimate)

family <- "sans"
gfb <- ggplot(df2, aes(
  y = rank,
  group = League,
  fill = factor(League, levels = colpal.order),
  color = factor(League, levels = colpal.order)
)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(x = goals),
    alpha = 0.8, color = NA,
    position = "identity", orientation = "y"
  ) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(
    aes(
      x = 0,
      y = rank,
      label = sprintf("<img src='%s' width='50'/>", image_file)
    ),
    hjust = 1,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    fill = NA,
    color = NA,
    label.padding = unit(5, "pt")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colpal, aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = goals,
      label = ifelse(goals > 0, sprintf("%1.0f", goals), "")
    ),
    color = "white",
    fontface = "bold", size = 14,
    family = family,
    vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1
  ) +
  # geom_text(
  #   aes(x = +15.5, y = 0, label = months(FULLDATE)),
  #   size = 5, color = "grey"
  # ) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(linewidth = .5, color = "#122623"),
    panel.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = "transparent"),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 60, unit = "pt"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff", color = NA),
    plot.title = element_text(
      size = 28, hjust = 0.5,
      face = "bold", color = "#21FA90",
      vjust = .5, family = family
    ),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(
      size = 17.5, hjust = 0.5, face = "italic", color = "grey",
      vjust = .5, family = family
    ),
    plot.caption = element_text(
      size = 12.5, color = "grey",
      vjust = 0, family = family
    )
  )

anim <- gfb +
  transition_states(
    FULLDATE,
    transition_length = 4,
    state_length = 2
  ) +
  view_follow(
    fixed_y = TRUE
  ) +
  ease_aes("quadratic-in-out") +
  enter_grow() +
  exit_shrink() +
  labs(
    title = "Goal scored this season",
    subtitle = "{closest_state}",
    caption = "Source: Hedgeflare calculation"
  )

anim



Thanks a lot! I was stuck on this one. How would you adjust the size of the logo though? I've seen ````geom_richtextas alabel.sizeparameter that can be passed toaes(). I've tried to add label.size=10``` but it's not working. Thanks
